# Why is my Tkinter calculator crashing with this code?

Tags: python, tkinter, crash, calculator

so I am learning a bit of Tkinter and now I wanted to make a calculator. I know that I can write the code much easier with some for loops, but here is my problem: when I press the equal button my program stops running. When I leave the "input" out, then it doesn´t crash. Can you help me to make it calculate? Here´s the code(the problem is marked):

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import math

BACK_COLOR = 'grey'

def add_one():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('1'))

def add_two():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('2'))

def add_three():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('3'))

def add_four():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('4'))

def add_five():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('5'))

def add_six():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('6'))

def add_seven():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('7'))

def add_eight():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('8'))

def add_nine():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('9'))

def add_zero():
   entry_box.insert(1000, str('0'))

def add_point():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('.'))

def clean():
    entry_box.delete(0, 'end')

def add_pi():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str(math.pi))

def add_plus():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('+'))

def add_minus():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('-'))

def add_mult():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('*'))

def add_divide():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('/'))

def add_raise():
    entry_box.insert(1000, str('^'))

def calculate():
    #here is the problem
    i = input(entry_box.get())
    ab = int(i)
    print(str(ab))

main_window = Tk()
main_window.resizable(False, False)
main_window.geometry('354x500')
main_window.title('Calculator Alpha')
main_window.configure(background=BACK_COLOR)

#logo
label_logo = Label(main_window, text='Calculator Alpha', padx=25,pady=10, background=BACK_COLOR)
label_logo.place(x=66, y=0)
label_logo.configure(font=('BlacklightD', 18))

#entrybox
entry_box = Entry(main_window, width=51)
entry_box.place(x=20, y=50)

#bottom row
button_equal = Button(main_window, text='=', padx=30, pady=25,     command=calculate)
button_equal.place(x=277,y=430)
button_plus = Button(main_window, text='+', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_plus)
button_plus.place(x=207,y=430)
button_pi = Button(main_window, text='Pi', padx=30, pady=25, command=add_pi)
button_pi.place(x=137,y=430)
button_zero = Button(main_window, text='0', padx=30, pady=25, command=add_zero)
button_zero.place(x=67,y=430)
button_point = Button(main_window, text='.', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_point)
button_point.place(x=0,y=430)

#second bottom row
button_mult = Button(main_window, text='*', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_mult)
button_mult.place(x=280, y=356)
button_minus = Button(main_window, text='-', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_minus)
button_minus.place(x=210, y=356)
button_three = Button(main_window, text='3', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_three)
button_three.place(x=141, y=356)
button_two = Button(main_window, text='2', padx=29, pady=25, command =     add_two)
button_two.place(x=69, y=356)
button_one = Button(main_window, text='1', padx=29, pady=25, command=add_one)
button_one.place(x=0, y=356)



#second top row
button_raise = Button(main_window, text='^', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_raise)
button_raise.place(x=277, y=282)
button_divide = Button(main_window, text='/', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_divide)
button_divide.place(x=210, y=282)
button_six = Button(main_window, text='6', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_six)
button_six.place(x=141, y=282)
button_five = Button(main_window, text='5', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_five)
button_five.place(x=67, y=282)
button_four = Button(main_window, text='4', padx=29, pady=25,     command=add_four)
button_four.place(x=0, y=282)

#top row
button_delete = Button(main_window, text='<-', padx=27, pady=25)
button_delete.place(x=278, y=208)
button_clean = Button(main_window, text='C', padx=27, pady=25, command=clean)
button_clean.place(x=213, y=208)
button_nine = Button(main_window, text='9', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_nine)
button_nine.place(x=141, y=208)
button_eight = Button(main_window, text='8', padx=30, pady=25,     command=add_eight)
button_eight.place(x=67, y=208)
button_seven = Button(main_window, text='7', padx=29, pady=25,     command=add_seven)
button_seven.place(x=0, y=208)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce this down to an [mcve]. If the program crashes when you click the equal button, for the purposes of this question you probably don't need any other buttons. Also, why are you calling `input`? What do you think that is doing?

Comment: def calculate():
        #here is the problem
        i = input(entry_box.get())
        ab = int(i)
        print(str(ab))

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Why would you ever use `input` in a GUI application?! That's just asking for trouble!

Comment: its not really an error when i click the equal button the programm frezze and when i wait i gives me "pythonw.exe doesnt react" (this is translatet)

Comment: i dont know i am new like i said and im not so good with all this stuff

Comment: You shouldn't be putting code in your program if you don't know what it does. Part of the learning process needs to be that you read the documentation on the functions that you're using for the first time.

Comment: well i did but i wasnt thinking of that that you arent allowed to use input but know i have learned it thank you for your help

Comment: @stybl It was not producing an error. It was just waiting for user input in the console however I think this did not interact well with tkinter and the program was crashing when he tried to interact with it while the `input()` method was waiting for a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is how you wrote your `calculate()` function.

This line `i = input(entry_box.get())` is not doing what you think it is doing.

What that line is doing is calling the `input()` method and printing the string result of `entry_box.get()` to the console and waiting for a reply from the user to input something. The program is essentially paused until you reply in the console. This is probably why your program is crashing.

To get the string of your math and then to have it calculated you can use the `eval` method. This will perform math on a math compatible string.

Change:

```
def calculate():
    #here is the problem
    i = input(entry_box.get())
    ab = int(i)
    print(str(ab))
```

To:

```
def calculate():
    i = entry_box.get()
    print (eval(i))
```

If you would rather have the results in the entry box you can do:

```
def calculate():
    i = entry_box.get()   
    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box.insert(0, eval(i))
```

One other note:

`entry_box.insert(1000, str('1'))` is not how you should write this.

Instead use `END` for the insertion point.

`entry_box.insert(END, str('1'))`

Do this to all your functions that are using insert and it will work as it should.

Comment: okay thank you rly much now its doing what i wanted thank yoouuuu :)

Comment: @gabryS I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps

Comment: oh i didnt saw it but it helped me i figured it out by my self and after that i saw yours and they are the same

Comment: @gabryS glad you figured it out. If my answer helped you get the results you were looking for please consider selecting the check box next to my answer to indicate your question has a solution.

Comment: Please don't recommend `eval` to unexperienced programmers. Especially not in a question that asks why the GUI is crashing.

Comment: #Rawing. I don't see the harm in `eval` doesn't it just perform math on a string as long as that string is a proper math function? Its not like I am recommending `exec`

Comment: @SierraMountainTech `eval` is only insignificantly less dangerous than `exec`. Try calling `eval` on this: `"__import__('os').system('echo Hi, I can run any code I want in here')"`

Comment: @Rawing Ah I thought that vonerability was an exec thing. I was under the impression that `eval` only worked on math. Thanks for the info.